# Compress Given String replacing the re-occurring characters with number of times they are occuring

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

```
public class Test12CompressString {
    public static String getCompressedString(String str) {
        String newString = "";
        int count = 1;
        int len = str.length()-1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= len ; i++) {
            if(i != len) {
                System.out.println(i);
                if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)) {
                    count++;
                    continue;
                } 
                if(count == 1) {
                    newString = newString+str.charAt(i);
                } else {
                    newString = newString+str.charAt(i)+count;
                }
                if ( str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1)) {
                    count = 1;
                    continue;
                }
            } 
        }
        return newString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abbbccccc";
        String ans = getCompressedString(str);
        System.out.print(ans);
    }

}
```

## Expected Output : ab3c4

## Output I am getting : ab3

Can someone tell what am I missing and why the last character and it's count is missing from my output?
Can someone correct my code?

Comment: Tip: You can debug it so you can survey each step in the loop what happens there. By this you can learn a lot. Every IDE like Eclipse or IDEA intelliJ supports debugging.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAWnIP1S6UA

Answer (score 0):

When the for loop ends your code just returns `newString`. The only place where your code adds a '4' is when the loop hits *a new character* and recognizes that this is no longer a `c`. At the very end, before `return newString`, you should check if `count` exceeds 1, and if so, print `count`.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the commentary above, when your loop finishes the string, the result for the last symbol is simply thrown away.

I offer approximately the same approach as you have with some improvements.

1. What if `null` was passed to your method? Your code will fall with exception. It seems to me it makes sense to return `null` in this case.
2. What if the argument string is empty, another words, its length is zero? This case must be considered separately.
3. The `String` class in Java are immutable. Therefore, each concatenation of the strings creates a new instance of the `String` object. To build the result in this such case, it is better to use a `StringBuilder`.
4. In your approach, you look forward when running along the string. You compare the current symbol with the following. To do this, you need carefully watch for index not exceeds the length of the string.  I propose to simplify this and not look forward at all.
5. This is not pretty and you probably have a way to do it better. But after the end of the cycle, we need to add a last symbol in the string. This is a repeating piece of code, so I put it into a separate function.

```
private static String getCompressedString(String str) {
    if (Objects.isNull(str)) return null;
    if (str.isEmpty()) return "";

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    char calculated = str.charAt(0);
    int repeats = 0;

    for (char observed : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (observed == calculated) {
            repeats++;
        } else {
            append(result, calculated, repeats);
            calculated = observed;
            repeats = 1;
        }
    }
    append(result, calculated, repeats);

    return result.toString();
}

private static void append(StringBuilder result, char calculated, int repeats) {
    result.append(calculated);
    if (repeats > 1) {
        result.append(repeats);
    }
}
```

I am completely sure that there is a way to make this code better and shorter. I hope it will serve as a starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String getCompressedString(String str) {
        String newString = "";
        int count = 1;
        int len = str.length() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1)) {
                count++;
                continue;
            }
            if (count == 1) {
                newString = newString + str.charAt(i);
            } else {
                newString = newString + str.charAt(i) + count;
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1)) {
                count = 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            newString = newString + str.charAt(len);
        } else {
            newString = newString + str.charAt(len) + count;
        }
        return newString;
    }
```

Comment: //    The problemwith yourcode is that you didn't add the value of the last letter to the string and that should be done after the end of the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CompressString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abbbccccc";
        String ans = getCompressedString(str);
        System.out.println("String is --->" + ans);
    }


    public static String getCompressedString(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        String newString = "";
        int count = 0;
        int len = str.length() - 1;
        char firstVar = str.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
            if (firstVar != str.charAt(i)) {
                if (count > 0) {
                    newString = newString + firstVar + count;
                } else {
                    newString = newString + firstVar;
                }
                count = 0;
                firstVar = str.charAt(i);
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            newString = newString + firstVar + count;
        } else {
            newString = newString + firstVar;
        }
        return newString;
    } }
```

Please check, this may help you.